# Logging LAN traffic with ebtables-iptables-ddwrt

Tags: networking, iptables, dd-wrt

**Goal**

I am trying to log internal(eth0->eth0[via br0]) traffic to syslog on DD-WRT.

**Problem**

Bridged traffic is not seen by iptables. The same traffic is also not visible via ebtables.

**Things I Tried**

I would post what I have already tried but I have basically tried everything, quick recap:

```
insmod ebt*  #load all ebtables and extensions

echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables

ebtables -t nat -A PREROUTING --logical-in br0 -p ipv4 -j redirect --redirect-target ACCEPT
```

add logging[as first rule] to all tables and chains of both ebtables and iptables

"trick" iptables by redirecting "bridged" traffic to the network layer

SETUP(basically stock DD-WRT v3):

br0 = eth0[lan] + ath0[wlan]

no static route

no STP

**What I Want**

**EDIT:

I want to log all traffic from 192.168.2.3(lan/eth0/br0) to 192.168.2.4(lan/eth0/br0), basically anything BETWEEN devices on eth0(lan ports)**

[I can log all other traffic crossing the bridge, from lan to wan and vice versa. After reviewing the logs I did in fact have this working very briefly via some combination of ebtables and iptables(example output:

```
2016-XX-XXTXX:XX:41-XX:00 XXXXX kernel: [  XXX.850000] ACCEPT_ebt IN=br0 OUT=br0 MAC=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX SRC=192.168.2.12 DST=192.168.2.16 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=35259 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=45879 DPT=22 etc....
`]
```

Point me in the right direction

Tell me what I'm doing wrong

Tell me how to achieve this

**lsmod**

```
Module                  Size  Used by
ebt_802_3                708  0 
ebt_among               2116  0 
ebt_arp                 1572  0 
ebt_arpreply            1060  0 
ebt_dnat                 804  0 
ebt_ip                  1252  0 
ebt_limit                948  0 
ebt_log                 2100  0 
ebt_mark                 692  0 
ebt_mark_m               628  0 
ebt_nflog                660  0 
ebt_pkttype              580  0 
ebt_redirect             868  0 
ebt_snat                 852  0 
ebt_stp                 1780  0 
ebt_ulog                2724  0 
ebt_vlan                 916  0 
ebtable_broute           756  0 
ebtable_filter           916  0 
ebtable_nat              916  0 
ebtables               14253  3 ebtable_broute,ebtable_filter,ebtable_nat
```

**route**

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.11.AA.BB     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ppp0
10.11.AA.BB     *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
10.137.0.0      SerVer          255.255.0.0     UG    0      0        0 br0
127.0.0.0       *               255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 lo
169.254.0.0     *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br0
192.168.2.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
```

Comment: This isn't exactly what you are looking for, but will get you to the same place: https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Network_traffic_analysis_with_netflow_and_ntop

Comment: Thank you [Argonauts](http://superuser.com/users/250153/argonauts), unfortunately rflow is not available in this build.

Comment: If you are still looking for help, could you provide a little more context?  Specifically, are looking to log all traffic that crosses from lan to wan, lan to lan AND wan to lan, or those two + a vpn or other traffic? The way I read it it sounds like you want everything.

Comment: @ [Argonauts](http://superuser.com/users/250153/argonauts) updated with more info, I can log everything EXCEPT lan to lan, which is what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

If by "devices on eth0" you mean an integrated hardware switch that gives you the usual four LAN ports on routers and a fifth port that shows up as `eth0` on the SoC, then you cannot do it that way, because the traffic stays in the hardware swith, never enters the SoC, and never appears on `eth0` or `br0`.

Depending on the hardware you have, you may be able to use `swconfig` to expose the actual switch ports as network interfaces to the kernel (e.g. VLAN interfaces `eth0.1` to `eth0.4`). Then you can add all of those to `br0`, and log traffic (and this configuration will also have significantly less bandwidth compared to the hardware switch).

But not all hardware does support this.